# How to set a constant opacity with the Pen tool in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, pen-tool

How to change the opacity of the shape pen tool in Photoshop without always having to go and click on the new shape? Every time you create a new shape the opacity goes back to 100, then I read that you can create a group and they stay the same opacity but then the color stays the same on all the shapes.

I am trying to vector a very detailed pen drawing and need the shapes to be low always so I can see the lines I am following in the layer underneath, but there must be a way to set the opacity low constantly to avoid always having to change the new shapes opacity.

Comment: If I remember correctly, select the previous layer created by pen tool, it should keep the same feature as opacity.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to draw your shapes under a group and set the opacity for the group once, you don't need to click on the layer every time. Opacity uses as default shortcut the number keys (<kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>0</kbd>).

Press <kbd>1</kbd>  to quickly set the opacity to 10%, <kbd>2</kbd> for 20%, etc. If you want to be more precise, quickly type 2 digits (type <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> to set it to 7%, for example).

There's no way to set the opacity of the shape before it is created, because it uses the default 100% *layer* opacity.